# HttpServletRequest unable to get body of request

Tags: java, json, servlets, tomcat10

I'm trying to create a little test servlet (Tomcat 10) to accept simple "POST" messages, however no matter what I've tried the servlet never seems to get the body (json).

I'm using Postman to send the messages (http).

I've tried `getReader()` and `getInputStream()` and both keep returning *nothing*. I've read that this can happen when the buffer has already been read, but I'm not reading it twice (not that I am aware of).

Here are some *debug* values:

`getContentLength()` => `-1`

`getContentType()` => `application/json`

`getReader().ready()` => `false`.

So, either no body was recieved or it was already read - but where? I've been using Postman for other API's without issue, so I don't believe I've done something wrong there, what else can I try within the servlet?

Does anyone have any suggestions of what I could try to get this working?

**Update**

Thank you @parsifal, I tested the servlet using PowerShell's `Invoke-WebRequest` and it worked perfectly, so I took another look at all my Postman settings, tested several things and then finally found my error. The Header parameter `Content-Length` wasn't selected - I had incorrectly assumed that it would be automatically sent, but it wasn't.

Comment: A POST request body consists of name-value pairs, and they are available via `getRequestParameter()`, not as the body. They are also decoded for you.

Comment: Hi @user207421, are you really sure about that? In postman I sent the "json" as "raw" (application/json) there is no option for providing a name/value pair for the body. Headers have name/value pairs. At any rate, I'll check/debug the parameters to see if I can find the payload/body.

Comment: Well you shouldn't have sent it that way, because you can't retrieve it that way, You should have sent it as a named parameter of the POST request.

Comment: You should have no problem retrieving the data this way, but the content length of -1 indicates to me that you're not actually sending a body. Perhaps try with `curl` rather than Postman? (@EJP - the only time `HttpServletRequest` should try to process the body as form data is if (1) you specify content type as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and (2) the servlet code requests parameter values).